# Is there any Ubuntu version for PSP and PS3?

Tags: installation, cd-image, ps3

Is there any Ubuntu version for PSP and PS3? If yes, where is the ISO files located?

I think it is impressive to have Ubuntu on PSP and PS3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. It is currently not possible to have Ubuntu or any other operating system on the PS3. [Sony killed the 'Other OS' feature](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/video-games/7538828/Sony-disables-PlayStation-3-OS-function.html). There is an expception: the 'Other OS' feature is disabled by firmware version 3.21 but still runs on older consoles that have firmware 3.15 or lower. This would mean though that there is no access possible to PSN or any other web feature since this will prompt for a (mandatory) update.

Any other methods installing another OS would be illegal in most countries (if not all). And even if it is not illegal... [circumvent Sony's PlayStation 3 security algorithms or run unauthorized software on your PS3 and Sony will sever your access to its PlayStation Network for good](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/02/16/official-statement-regarding-ps3-circumvention-devices-and-pirated-software/). It involves hacking your PS3 but AU is not going to provide you with the instructions to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes for PS3 there is " yellow dog 6.1 distro " and here is a tutorial on how you can download and install it : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkBM9sSdh50&feature=related 
however for psp I don't know if it works this , but for PS3 I'm sure it works .Oh ye I forgot ,yellow dog is based on linux ,but not on ubuntu , but is the only linux I know for PS3 ,however it works fine.

Comment: I think the Yellow Dog is based CentOS, not Ubuntu.

Comment: what about XboX?

Comment: This video is from before Sony took out the other OS option so will NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have Ubuntu installed sin 2008 in my PS3, but I didn't updated the PS3 software since 3.21. I run Ubuntu 12.10 in my PS3.

now the effort to install a linux version in the new PS3 are hack, nothing legal.

if you have an old one with software version 3.21 or less you can check this: http://www.playstation.com/ps3-openplatform/index.html

the site psubuntu.com is closed.